# Plotting an optimization solution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using the following function along with [`fminunc`](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/toolbox/optim/fminunc.html) to draw plot's,

```
function stop = bananaout(x, optimValues, state)
    stop = false;
    hold on;
    plot(x(1),x(2),'.');
    drawnow
end
```

My plot looks like the following,

[image]

How can I make it to look like the following?

Do I need to modify my `bananaout` or the driver program?

[image]

**Source Code**

```
    function [x, fval, eflag, iter, fcount] = Optimization_With_Steepest_Descent(start_point)
    fun = @(x)(100*(x(2) - x(1)^2)^2 + (1 - x(1))^2);
    x0 = start_point;

    % optimoptions setup
    options = optimoptions('fminunc','Display','off', 'OutputFcn',@bananaout,'Algorithm','quasi-newton');
    options = optimoptions(options,'HessUpdate','steepdesc', 'MaxFunEvals',600);

    % call fminunc
    [x,fval,eflag,output] = fminunc(fun,x0,options);


    title 'Rosenbrock solution via steepest descent'

    iter = output.iterations;
    fcount = output.funcCount;

    disp('Press any key to continue...');
end
```

Comment: I'm very positive that you  are actually not supposed to do that. I think what you are supposed to do is to see the convergence towards the minima on the contour plot. You need to plot both for that. **1.** What you actually are plotting. **2.** [**`contour`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) plot . Either that or I am mistaken. But either way, what you are looking for is  [**`contour`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html)

Comment: Even without `contour` you should first save all the steps in different columns in `x` and `y`, and then use `plot(x,y)` to plot them all at once, there is no need to draw the lines one by one in a loop.